# Testing image classification model on new images

Tags: tensorflow

I am still a bit new to deep learning.

```
def predictionrelease(preds):
    arr=[]
    for i in range(0,len(preds)):
        ans=np.argmax(preds[i])
        arr.append(ans)
    len(arr)
    return arr
dir_path = 'predict'
for i in os.listdir(dir_path):
    img = image.load_img(dir_path+ '\\' + i, target_size = (200,200,3))
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    X = image.img_to_array(img)
    X = np.expand_dims(X, axis = 0)
    images = np.vstack([X])
val = predictionrelease(model.predict(images))
print(val)
```

I was able to train a model on image classification. Now i try to predict new images in a single file using the model, but it's end up predicting only one of the images, whereas i want it to give prediction for all the of the images in the file. I iterated over the images, but it's seems not to be working. There is the code:

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use the code below to predict on all images present in a folder.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

dir_path = path_to_the_folder

images=[]
for i in os.listdir(dir_path):
    img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(dir_path + i, target_size = (200,200,3))
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    X = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
    X = np.expand_dims(X, axis = 0)
    images.append(X)

arr=[]
pred=[]
for i in range(len(images)):    
  pred.append(model.predict(images[i],))
  ans=np.argmax(pred)
  arr.append(ans)
        
print(arr)
```